# Mysql selecting and sorting by the bigger field

Tags: mysql

I have two fields on my table, lets say date_created and date_updated

I  want to select 20 recently updated/created records

so it means i have to choose the top dates from both fields, how do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

found it!

greatest(field1,field2)